# Why can boost asio udp connection throw "send: Connection refused"?

Tags: c++, exception, boost, udp, boost-asio

I assumed that udp connection does not really care if there is any peer at all on the other side so why could boost asio udp connection throw "send: Connection refused" on `socket->send( boost::asio::buffer( data.get(), length ) );` call (I am sending from Linux to Windows, only sending not trying to read any thing)? Is it some network card error or what could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost.Asio is throwing an error with a value of `boost::asio::error::connection_refused` because the underlying socket's `send*()` operation is returning an error code of `ECONNREFUSED`.  Per the [udp](http://linux.die.net/man/7/udp) manual page, `send*()` functions are permitted to return `ECONNREFUSED`:

> All errors documented for [socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) or [ip](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) may be returned by a send or receive on a UDP socket.
>
> **ECONNREFUSED** 
>       No receiver was associated with the destination address. This might be caused by a previous packet sent over the socket.

While it can be odd to receive a connection related error on a connectionless protocol, the service is still permitted to return detected errors.  The unreliable part of the protocol prevents the caller from receiving acknowledgement that the a message was received by the destination. However, this does not preclude the service from reporting a connection refused error if it knows the destination did not receive the message.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`send_to`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/send_to/overload1.html). After all, UDP is a connectionless protocol.

Comment: I meant on established connection after some time. Exception comes and goes during application execution on one connection. Meaning we have sent at rate 1 message a second. and we can send 100 messages, then get 10 exceptions then send 1000 more messages on same connection sucsessfully.

Comment: @DuckQueen: Giving it a little bit more thought, forget about `.connect` and `.send` and just use `send_to`. Whether it's possible to actually connect to a UDP socket depends on the OS, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741392/can-you-bind-and-connect-both-ends-of-a-udp-connection.

Comment: As non-intuitive as it is, [UDP](http://linux.die.net/man/7/udp) is permitted to return an `ECONNREFUSED` error even though it is a connection-less protocol.

Comment: @TannerSansbury it works by the mechanism of ICMP Destination Unreachable (Port Unreachable) messages.