# TCP vs. UDP socket latency benchmark

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

I have implemented a small benchmark for socket communication via TCP and UDP in Python. Surprisingly, TCP is almost exactly double as fast as UDP.

To avoid routing effects, server and client are running on the same Unix machine, but on different threads.

Maybe the code is useful. Here is the server code:

```
import socket
import sys

host = 'localhost'  
port = 8888
buffersize = 8
server_address = (host, port) 

def start_UDP_server():
    socket_UDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    socket_UDP.bind(server_address)

    print("UDP server is running...")

    while True:
        data, from_address = socket_UDP.recvfrom(buffersize)
        if not data: break
        socket_UDP.sendto(data, from_address)
    socket_UDP.close()


def start_TCP_server():
    socket_TCP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_TCP.bind(server_address)
    socket_TCP.listen(1)

    print("TCP server is running...")

    while True:    
        client, client_address = socket_TCP.accept()

        while True:
            data = client.recv(buffersize)
            if not data: break
            client.sendall(data)

        client.close()
```

So you can run either `start_TCP_server()` or `start_UDP_server()`.

On client side the code is:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

host = 'localhost'  
port = 8888
buffersize = 8
server_address = (host, port) 
client_address = (host, port+1)
N = 1000000


def benchmark_UDP():
    socket_UDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
    socket_UDP.bind(client_address)

    print("Benchmark UDP...")

    duration = 0.0
    for i in range(0, N):
        b = bytes("a"*buffersize, "utf-8")
        start = time.time()
        socket_UDP.sendto(b, server_address)
        data, from_address = socket_UDP.recvfrom(buffersize)
        duration += time.time() - start

        if data != b:
            print("Error: Sent and received data are bot the same")

    print(duration*pow(10, 6)/N, "µs for UDP") 


def benchmark_TCP():
    socket_TCP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_TCP.connect(server_address)

    print("Benchmark TCP...")

    duration = 0.0
    for i in range(0, N):
        b = bytes("a"*buffersize, "utf-8")
        start = time.time()
        socket_TCP.sendall(b)
        data = socket_TCP.recv(buffersize)
        duration += time.time() - start

        if data != b:
            print("Error: Sent and received data are bot the same")

    print(duration*pow(10, 6)/N, "µs for TCP")
    socket_TCP.close()
```

Like for the server you can start the benchmark by `benchmark_TCP()` or `benchmark_UDP()`.

The results are about **25 µs for TCP**, and about **54 µs for UDP** on Unix and even worse for Windows (about 30 µs for TCP and more than 200 µs for UDP). Why? I would expect a minimal advantage for UDP.

Comment: Could be related to the size of the data you're sending and MTU size [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/638446/429982)

Comment: No, because my question is not about throughput, but the software overhead (avoiding network configuration issues, etc.). I want to measure a ping-pong message 10^6 times and not how many bytes can be pressed through the wire. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: This is a bit apples and oranges. For UDP, you sending to a socket each time, which means resolving hostname to IP address, etc. for every send/receive. For TCP you setup the connection once and then send data over that connection each time. It might be more like Tangerines vs Seville if for TCP you put the connection setup/close in the loop. But either way your single latency metric only reflects one aspect of UDP vs TCP - the latency - but there are other factors like reliability and throughput which can also be important.

Comment: With regard to the comment from barny, jack up the buffersize to 64000 and see who's winning TCP or UDP

Comment: If I use a larger buffer size, both are slightly slower, which makes sense due to larger copy operations.

Comment: Rolf of Saxony - "winning" - if you only want to send 32 bytes, what's the point of measuring performance with 64k and using that to declare a winner? @Michale Dorner's test also skims over the fact UDP is probably less reliable than TCP - but a test within a single machine is very unlikely to expose that difference in reliability of delivery. That's metrics for you - you need to understand the circumstances of the measurement before you can start to compare the results.

Comment: Reliability is not the main goal. Actually it is speed and performance.

Comment: maybe you can analyze what is happening using `tcpdump` or `Wireshark`

Comment: This benchmark seems to apply only to LAN; over the Internet results will be extremely different due to packet loss. Indeed, TCP and UDP are known to have pretty much the same latencies - as long as there is a zero packet loss. If simulating, say, 1% packet loss and 100ms RTT(say, with netem) - results will be very different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your TCP socket is connected but your UDP socket is not. This means extra processing for every send/receive on the UDP socket. Call `connect` on [each side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741392/can-you-bind-and-connect-both-ends-of-a-udp-connection) for the UDP socket, just like you call `connect`/`accept` on the TCP socket.

Programs like `iperf` do this to measure accurately.

Comment: iperf does not offer a roundtrip measure for TCP.

Comment: You are completely right. Although UDP is connection-less, [using this code](https://gist.github.com/michaeldorner/eaefb3fc7f5ccfb32fc6) results in *24 µs for UDP* and *25 µs for TCP*.

Comment: For `buffersize = 8000` instead of 8 like before, we get 28 µs for TCP and 30 µs for UDP.

Comment: Does this mean that TCP is "better/faster" than UDP without connect? Would it be possible to link more information about this? I actually never saw a statement like this in all the documentation I read. I only care about speed so my question is : for a lot of sends and recv what is faster globally and for each sending? (TCP / UDP / "UDP with connect"/ ...)

Comment: @Waroulolz Well, they have a variety of advantages and disadvantages. One disadvantage when sending a UDP datagram on an unconnected socket is that the work needed to locally plumb to the destination has to be done on each datagram sent.